# Does a constant magnetic field induce an emf in space irrespective of what is inside the space?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I came across a question which was a pyq from an Indian examination.The question states; An insulting rod of length L is falling with a velocity v perpendicular to B as well as perpendicular to L. Induced emf between the two rods is? The answer to the above question as given in the answer key is zero and the explanation says that: as the rod is insulating there is no emf induced. Please explain

Comment: who did the rod insult?

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

It matters not what the material of the rod is.
If the rod was a metal there would be a migration of the free/mobile electrons and in an insulator the motion of the rod through the magnetic field would produce a polarisation of the atoms/molecules.
In both cases the induced emf would be the same with the insulator being a source of emf with an extremely high source/internal resistance.